# calculate index using $|G|=|H|[G:H]$

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a subgroup, we obtain the important *Counting Formula* to calculate The number of left cosets:
>
> $$|G|=|H|[G:H]$$
>
> Here $[G:H]$ is called *index*.

**Two cases:**

1. $G=\mathbb{Z},+$, $H=\mathbb{2Z},+$. In this case index is $2$.
2. $G=GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, $H=SL_n(\mathbb{R})$. In this case index is infinity.

**My Question:**

In both cases $|G|,|H|$ are infinite. So how can we easily$*$ check if *index* is finite or not.

$*$by *easily* I mean if there is a ready-made formula for that.

Note: If this post has been posted before please give me the link. I will delete this post.

Comment: In the first case, it is clear that $H$ and $1 + H$ partition $G$, so there are two cosets.

Comment: @ZainPatel I know that, but my question is different.

Comment: One way to do this is to construct a surjective homomorphism $f : G\to K$, where $K$ is a finite group such that $\ker(f) = H$.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan what is $K$?

Comment: @MANMAID In short there is no such rule. But as Prahlad said, if you can prove $G/H \cong K$ where $K$ is any finite group, then you conclude $H$ is of finite index.

Comment: Thanks @S.C. and Prahlad.